# How to create a button that makes an object move in Corona

Tags: android, ios, button, lua, coronasdk

How do I make a LEFT and RIGHT button which moves an object left and right when holding them and a JUMP button which makes an object jump and then come back down before being able to jump again (With the code I had using linearvelocity, I could tap the JUMP button multiple times so the object kept gaining height).

I'm pretty new to Corona and I have a lot of issues like these..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me give an example.

Create Button Left add listener then on receiving the event use transition on the object.

Second when it is transiting, tap jump button, add tap event not touch, otherwise it'll keep going up.
On tap make a condition.

```
if alreadyJumping == true then
  --don't jump
else
    charater.y=charater.y-jumpHieght
    timer.performWithDelay(500,function() charater.y=charater.y+jumpHieght end) 
end
```